# Cordova - AdMob plugins can show test ads but not showing real ads

Tags: cordova, admob

No code listing.
I tried both cordova-plugin-admobpro and cordova-plugin-admob-simple.
Both can show test ads, but after removing isTesting=true attribute I get "Error 0 - Internal Error" in response.

I also tried using the working code that I used half year ago - same result!

I checked different app on my AdMob account - it shows ads, so account is not blocked. BUT my app was blocked once and then un-blocked by Google.

I use the latest Cordova version at this moment (5.1.1).

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I also face same problem. If you get any solution please post here.

Comment: I posted an answer. For me it worked after ~40 days without my influence. What about you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of April 2016 I noticed impressions in my AdMob stats. It took about 40 days for AdMob to start showing ads.
Looks like it is not related to code/configuration, but related to AdMob behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you've just create new ads, you might need to wait a few minutes/hours for it to show some ads...
You can also show alert messages when you get certain events.

```
function onAdmobEvent (message) {
    //do some on admob event
     alert('onAdmobEvent ' + message );
}   

document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onBannerDismiss, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onBannerFailedReceive, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onBannerLeaveApplication, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onBannerPresent, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onBannerReceive, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialDismiss, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialFailedReceive, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialLeaveApplication, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialPresent, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialReceive, onAdmobEvent, false);
```